# Chrome extension Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

## I cant register the service worker of my chrome extension

**Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15**.

I'm trying to get the data of the input fields on some website and store it in the firestore

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";


chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    FIREBASE_CONFIGURATION
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


  // Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  
});
```

**Chrome error**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ut7.png)

**Here's my manifest**

```
{
  "name": "Input Logger",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Logs and stores user inputs from text fields and text areas.",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "background"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.mjs"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "images/icon.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ]
}
```

> i tried renaming the js to mjs, and it says "
> The error message "Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15" means that the service worker script could not be registered successfully. The status code of 15 indicates that the service worker script is not a module."

Comment: 1) You can't use NPM packages directly without compiling the code in webpack or a similar bundler. 2) Firbase may be incompatible with a service worker so you'll have to use it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).